# Does chrome has xml parser? if so, how do I enable it?

Tags: google-chrome, xml, msxml

I'm trying to find out if there's an xml parser for chrome, like we have the microsoft xml parser for IE browsers.

Comment: What would you expect this XML parser to look like or do? There *is* an XML parser of some sorts for Chrome; just open an XML file from disk to look at it.

Comment: the problem, @allquixotic, is that I'm using browserhawk to detect system compatibility and it detects only a microsoft xml parser (which can be found only in IE, as u can imagine), but it was asked to me to detect an xml parser in chrome/firefox/opera too.. but I was trying to prove it cannot be done and I can only detect if it is capable to read xml or not in these browsers